# Where are macOS icons stored?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, icon, menu-bar

[image]

For example, icons in the tray, where are these icons stored? Can they be modified (without installing third-party software)?

```
sh-3.2# system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType 
Software:

    System Software Overview:

      System Version: macOS 10.13.4 (17E199)
      Kernel Version: Darwin 17.5.0
      Boot Volume: lily
      Boot Mode: Normal
      Computer Name: lily’s MacBook Air
      User Name: System Administrator (root)
      Secure Virtual Memory: Enabled
```

Comment: Various places.  If you take the first one (Time Machine) as example: `/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/TimeMachine.menu/Contents/Resources/TMIdle.pdf`

Comment: The second one (AirPort) is a bit harder to find: `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreWLANKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Assets.car` and you might want some additional software to view those files (something like [ThemeEngine] (https://github.com/alexzielenski/ThemeEngine)

Comment: The menus you see in the *dock* are a part of each application bundle. the .menu items in /system/library (etc) show up the menu bar. And that is not a "tray" it's just the menu bar. Good luck changing those...